# explaining the different values for pointers and sizeof struct

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, typedef

I am new here an I am also new to programming. I am learning structs, pointers and functions and how they all work together in C. I am trying to make sense of the results I am getting for the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  int* data;
  unsigned int len;
} intarr_t;

intarr_t* intarr_create( unsigned int len )
{
  intarr_t* parr= malloc(sizeof(intarr_t));
  parr->data= malloc(len*sizeof(int));
  parr->len= len;

  if (parr->data && parr)
    return parr;
  else
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{ 
  intarr_t* p = intarr_create(3); //creat a typedef struct "intarr_t" with data pointer that has 3 integer values allocate to it.
  printf("%ld %ld %ld %ld %ld %ld %ld\n",sizeof(p), sizeof(*p), sizeof(*(p->data)), sizeof(p->data), sizeof(*(&(p->data))), sizeof(&(p->data)), sizeof(p->data[0]));
  printf("%p %p %p %p %p\n", (void*)p, (void*)p->data, (void*)&(p->len), (void*)&(p->data), (void*)&(p->data[0]));
  intarr_destroy(p);
}
```

I am getting this same output to what ever I set "len" to.

```
8 16 4 8 8 8 4
0x55f672e0c260 0x55f672e0c280 0x55f672e0c268 0x55f672e0c260 0x55f672e0c280
```

can someone please explain each one of the results and the corresponding part from the code? which one refer to the pointer, the pointer for data and the values in data, the derefrencing of each one? why sizes are what they result to be? why size of address data changes in each option and how come none change when I change how many elements (len) size?
This code I constructed got me more confused on the whole what is what and how to distinguish concepts from others.
Sorry for the messy long question. Again It's my first, so be nice with your criticism and be thorough with your answer. Thanks.

Comment: p.s. sizeof(int)=4 and sizeof(unsighed int)=4 in my machine.

Comment: Aside: the test for `NULL`-ness of `parr` in `if (parr->data && parr)` is too late to be useful.  It should be right after `intarr_t* parr= malloc(...`

Comment: Specifically, which of the values on `8 16 4 8 8 8 4` are unexpected for you?  What values did you expect?

Comment: BTW, you really need to check that `parr` isn't null before assigning to `parr->data` or `parr->len`.

Answer (score 2):

```
8 - sizeof(p) - size of a pointer to struct inarr_t which is the same as size of any pointer 
16 - sizeof(*p) - size of struct inarr_t consisting of an int and a pointer with padding 
4 - sizeof(*(p->data)) - size of int
8 - sizeof(p->data) - size of pointer to int which is the same as size of any pointer 

8 - sizeof(*(&(p->data))) - size of pointer to int (*& is dereferencing a pointer to pointer) 
8 - sizeof(&(p->data)) - size of pointer to pointer to int
4 - sizeof(p->data[0])) - size of int (the first element of int array)
```

No matter, what the size of `len` is, the above values will not change.

Note: The C standard does not require pointers of different types to have the same size - even though it is common. And this seems to be the case on your system.

Comment: "... which is the same as size of any pointer" --> C does not require pointers of different types to all have the same size - even though it is common.  A typical difference occurs when pointer to functions differ in size from pointers to objects.

Comment: @chux: Updated the answer with your input.